# How should I check if BufferedWriter is already closed?

Tags: java, file-handling, bufferedwriter

In android, I am writing a file on clicking a button and on clicking next time, it saves the file and closes the buffered writer. But, I also want to implement functionality to close the buffered writer in onDestroy function. Before that I need to know if `Bufferedwriter` is already closed. How will I check if Buffered Writer is already closed?

In addition to that, does `bufferedWriter.close()` function set `bufferedWriter` to `null`?

Comment: `if (writer !  = null)` then close it.

Comment: "does bufferedWriter.close() function set bufferedWriter to null" No, this is impossible. `bufferedWriter` is just a reference to a `BufferedWriter` instance; that instance can have zero or more references to it, and it has no way to know what actually does refer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `close` method on already closed Writer has no impact.

Still, if you want to know if the Writer is closed, you can call `writer.flush()`, if it throws `IOException` then it means the Writer is already closed.

For your second question, closing a stream doesn't nullify the reference. You have to explicitly set it to `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if `bufferredWriter` not equal to null

```
if(bufferredWriter!=null)
{
bufferredWriter.close();
}
```

If you are using java7 or more then you need not to worry about closing the BufferredWriter

JDK 7 onwards you can make you of try with resource

for example

```
try(BufferredWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferredWriter())
{

//your code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedWriter vf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file"));

    if (vf != null)
    {
        vf.close();
        vf.close(); //won't cause any problem
    }
```

you can close `BufferedWriter` as many times as you want if it is not null. So no need to check specifically if `BufferedWriter` is open or not.

Even better if you surround close statement in try/catch in case IOException occurs.

From javadocs

> Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

And as explained by sidgate, closing a stream won't nullify the reference you have to assign it manually.

Comment: Wow, that's new to me. Can you provide any explanation behind this behaviour?

Comment: from javadocs `Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.`. I simply referred javadoc. :)

Answer (score 0):

bufferedWriter.close() - Closes this writer. The contents of the buffer are flushed, the target writer is closed, and the buffer is released. Only the first invocation of close has any effect.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close())

Also, you can check like this

Define below 2 variables as instance variable

```
BufferedWriter bufferWriter;
boolean isOpen = false;
```

Then,

```
try {
    if (!isOpen) {
        bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        bufferWriter.write(initialData);
        isOpen = true;
    }
    bufferWriter.write(remainingData);
    bufferWriter.flush();
    Log.d(TAG, "written to file:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.v("IOException", e.toString());
}
```